# Communicate between fragments and layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I don't really know how to ask this question but I will start off with the idea here.

So I have a MainFragment that contains a SlidingUpPanelLayout that includes a viewpager and a layout that hold the controls for the application.

And what I want to do is when I change between fragments in the tablayout I want to change the layout of that holds the controls, I also want to trigger functions from the fragment with the controls in on my different fragments in the viewpager.

But since they are in different fragments I don't know how to get the control layouts and buttons to change and get a hold of them.

So here is first an image of the layout:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ1rE.jpg

And here is how my following XML looks like:
XML for the Control Content:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/control"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#000"
android:clickable="false"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/controlBackground"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorText"
    app:tabMode="scrollable"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorText">
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/takePicture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorText"
        android:clickable="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/flipCamera"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|left"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:tint="@color/colorText"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorText"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_camera_front_24px" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/openGallery"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|right"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/fox"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|top"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Pete is king!"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/info"
            style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|end"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:tint="@color/colorAccent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_shutterowl_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is my viewpager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <owlapps.shutterowl.AutoFitTextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/control"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

They are all showed together in a SlideUpPanelLayout like so:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
sothree:layout_constraintHeight_max="80dp"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="120dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
sothree:umanoOverlay="true">

<include layout="@layout/camera_content"/>

<include layout="@layout/control_content"/>


</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

I had an idea to solve this with a interface that could trigger functions from the MainFragment that loads the camera and content layouts, here is what i tried:

In a click event from the mainfragment: Tab1Fragment.take.visible(true);

My interface looks like this:

```
public interface CameraControlListener {
void visible(boolean status);
}
```

And is implemented in the Tab1Fragment that holds the camera view:

```
@Override
public void visible(boolean status) {
    if(status){
        takePicture();
    }
}
```

So how can I get all these to speak with eachother?
As i move between fragments i want the controls to change that are inside another fragment and also trigger functions from the active tabfragment in the viewpager.

Comment: The activity holding all these fragments should be coordinating the communication. The fragments should never directly communicate.

Comment: Ok. I tried from the mainactivity to get hold of objects in the other fragment but did get a null pointer exception since the items are in different fragments.

Comment: Did you go through FragmentManager and use findFragmentById() or findFragmentByTag()?

Comment: Can I really use fragmentmanager since the XML in the layout is not a fragment or should I just change it to a fragment instead of linearlayout

Comment: You can use FragmentManager to get a hold of a fragment if the fragment was added with an ID or tag.  If you want a change to the active fragment in a view pager to trigger other behavior, you probably want to attach an OnPageChangeListener to the pager.

Comment: Thats exactly my idea. But how to i trigger functions in the fragment from my mainfragment?

Comment: Step 1, get a reference to the fragment you want to call a method on. This process will vary depending how everything is structured. If you're inside 1 fragment, you'll probably have to call getActivity() to get a reference to the activity. If needed, cast the activity to the proper type (or use an interface type) and then call methods on the activity. From the activity, use FragmentManager to get a reference to the target fragment you want.  Step 2, cast the fragment to the appropriate type.  Finally step 3, call/trigger the method you want.

Comment: From 1 fragment, you could also call getActivity().getFragmentManager() (or getSupportFragmentManager()) to attempt to directly access another sibling fragment.  However, this is discouraged because it creates dependencies between fragments.  As I said early, it's better to have the activity coordinate all that.  But just wanted to give you another option.

Comment: One more suggestion, you can also use the getFragments() method in FragmentManager to get a list of all the fragments in an activity. You can loop through this list and use instanceof to locate the exact fragment you are looking for. Then cast it, then call your method on it.  Hope all this helps.